# How to set request code in Activity Result API?

Tags: android, kotlin, registerforactivityresult

I'm migrating from startActivityForResult to the Activity Result API. I have custom contract and a launcher:

```
private val gameContract=object: ActivityResultContract<Int, GameActivity.GameResult?>() {
        override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Int?): Intent {
            return Intent(this@SelectorActivity, GameActivity::class.java)
        }

        override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): GameActivity.GameResult? {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                val data = intent?.getStringExtra("data")
                data?.let {
                    return Gson().fromJson(it, GameActivity.GameResult::class.java)
                }
                return null
            }
            return null
        }
    }

    private val gameLauncher=registerForActivityResult(gameContract){
        //
    }
```

When I start activity with `gameLauncher.launch(0)` I got exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can only use lower 16 bits for
> requestCode

I tried different inputs with the same result
Apparently it expects requestCode to be set. But the API has no means to set it.
I thought the main purpose of this API is to get rid of messy request codes

So how do I start the activity with custom contract?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was is that I forgot to add dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.3.2'
```